# Add user to other user's primary group

Tags: debian, users

I have a user `tom` whose primary group is also `tom`. I'd like to add another user `jerry` to that group. Running

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G tom jerry
```

has no effect at all (also after logging out and back in again). When I try to create a group `tom` I get:

```
$ sudo groupadd tom
groupadd: group 'tom' already exists
```

but interestingly

```
$ sudo adduser jerry tom
Adding user `jerry' to group `tom' ...
gpasswd: group 'tom' does not exist in /etc/group
adduser: `/usr/bin/gpasswd -a jerry tom' returned error code 3. Exiting.
```

and also

```
$ getent group tom
tom:x:10000:tom,www-data
```

Is there anything I can do short of manually editing `/etc/group`?

Comment: What does `getent group tom` produce? Does it match `grep ^tom: /etc/group`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Added `getent` ouput to the question.

Comment: @Rahul wouldn't that set tom's primary group to `jerry`? That's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: @hauptbenutzer you mentioned that you want to add another user `jerry` to `tom`'s primary group

Comment: @Rahul, that doesn't mean making `tom`'s primary group `jerry`... As I understand it the desired result is `tom:x:10000:tom,www-data,jerry` in `/etc/group`, but achieved using administration tools rather than editing `/etc/group` directly — in particular, the `gpasswd` failure is odd and warrants some investigation.

Comment: @StephenKitt I am not making `tom`'s primary group `jerry`, I am adding `jerry` in `tom`'s primary group, that's what OP has mentioned in question If I've got you and OP right

Comment: @Rahul as I understand it the `jerry` user already exists and has a primary group (otherwise `usermod -a -G tom jerry` wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: @Rahul and `useradd -g jerry tom` tries to create a new `tom` user whose primary group is `jerry`.

Comment: @StephenKitt oh my bad, that was typo. Actually I intended to suggest `useradd -g tom jerry`

Comment: Is group tom in /etc/group or is it defined somewhere else (NIS, LDAP)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick As indicated by the adduser output, the group `tom` is really not present in `/etc/group`, there's also no NIS or LDAP configured. In fact, I couldn't even tell you where it is defined (ie. why useradd complains about its existence).

Comment: What's the output of `grep group /etc/nsswitch.conf` ? You'll need to either edit the `tom` group at wherever its name source is, or manually add it to a name source that has higher priority.